# Sending Mail With asp

Tags: email, vbscript, asp-classic

I am using the following code for sending email. The problem is that its sending email to all domains like gmail, live, yahoo, etc.. It's sending the email properly, but when I am sending it to my domain, it's showing me an error.

```
The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.
```

```vb
set omail = Server.CreateObject("CDO.Message")
Set objConfig = Server.CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")
Set Confi = objConfig.Fields
confi("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "localhost"
Confi("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
confi("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25
Confi.Update
Set omail.Configuration = objConfig
'omail.To = "ABC@gmail.com"
omail.To = "ABC@ABCXYZ.com"
omail.From = Test@gmail.com"
omail.subject = "From : Test"
omail.TextBody = vBody
omail.Send
```

I can not find the problem.

Comment: Depending on which version of IIS you are using you will need to "Send Errors to the Browser" and may even need to set "Detailed Errors" under custom errors for all requests. At the moment you're not getting any detail about the HTTP 500 Error that is occurring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding syntax highlighting to the question shows up the problem;

```vb
omail.From = Test@gmail.com"
```

Should be

```vb
omail.From = "Test@gmail.com"
```

You're missing a double quote (`"`) to start the string, this will cause a syntax error in VBScript which will in-turn generates a `HTTP 500 Internal Server Error` from IIS.